# Merging 3 sets of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am consider new to c++ and I have facing some doubt on merging three set of arrays.
For example:

```
x = 2,3,1,4,5
y = 1,3,5,7,9
z = 3,5,4,6,1
```

I would like to merge them into:

```
w = 2,1,3,3,3,5,1,5,4,4,7,6,5,9,1
```

I have been searching through Google. However what I get is how to merge the arrays and put them in an ascending orders.

What I actually needed:

```
1st from x, 1st from y, 1st from z, 2nd from x, 2nd from y, 2nd from z ............ 5th from z
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What should happen if arrays are of different sizes?

Comment: What type are your arrays? `std::vector<int>`? `int*`?

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA If the arrays are different sizes... he doesn't say, so we don't have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: The arrays are in different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of making a loop with `i` from `0` to `4` and mapping every `i` to the corresponding element of the array `w`.

Here's the skeleton of the algorithm:

```
std::array<int, 5>   x, y, z;
std::array<int, 15>  w;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    w[i*3]   = x[i];
    w[i*3+1] = y[i];
    w[i*3+2] = z[i];
}
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f66e6d3cee97747a)'s the working example.

---

If you are using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), then the algorithm gets a little bit trickier. You'll need to find the maximum size, using [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) for example, and perform a loop based on that value. Then whenever a vector is empty, you'll need to skip it. Here's the skeleton again:

```
std::vector<int> x, y, z;
std::vector<int> w;
std::size_t max = std::max({x.size(), y.size(), z.size()});
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    if (x.size() > i) w.push_back(x[i]);
    if (y.size() > i) w.push_back(y[i]);
    if (z.size() > i) w.push_back(z[i]);
}
```

Comment: the size of array is random.

Comment: @Marcus, what type is the "array"?

Comment: What do you mean by type? it consist of integer only

Comment: @Jefffrey Since the question is C++, we can assume `std::vector<T>` unless specified otherwise.  (For this sort of thing, in practice, nothing else makes sense.)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the size of x, y, z, and w, this is a fairly straightforward solution.

In C++, unlike other higher-level programming languages, most array-based operations are not handled by special functions. Instead, the user is required to write a loop to do this task themselves.

In your case, *assuming* that x, y, z, and w are all declared and defined properly, the most straightforward way is probably using a for loop, as follows:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<(size_of_x); i++){

    w[i*3] = x[i];
    w[i*3+1] = y[i];
    w[i*3+2] = z[i];

}
```

Notice that the variable `size_of_x` will need to be defined for this to work.

Comment: Last string `w[i*3+2] = x[i];` should be `w[i*3+2] = z[i];`

Answer (score 1):

How about some C++11?

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{

   std::vector<int> x {2,3,1,4,5}, y {1,3,5,7,9}, z {3,5,4,6,1};
   std::vector<int> w;
   for (int i {}; i < x.size(); ++i)
   {
      w.insert(v.end(),{x[i], y[i], z[i]});
    }
}
```

Comment: So, for you, C++11 is synonym of "brackets initialization"? Also don't use `using namespace std`.

Comment: No, but my solution requires a compiler with support of C++11, and why not `using namespace` for this small example?

Comment: Can you please remove the `using namespace std` so that I can remove the downvote?

Comment: If that is all, sure!

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to consider the fact that the lengths of the arrays may differ.

```
int *resArray;
int totalLength = sizeof(x) + sizeof(y) + sizeof(z);
int maxLength = max(sizeof(x), max(sizeof(y), sizeof(x)); 

resArray = new int[totalLength];

int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
{
    if (i < sizeof(x))
    {
        resArray[j] = x[i];
        j++
    }
    if (i < sizeof(y))
    {
        resArray[j] = y[i];
        j++
    }
    if (i < sizeof(z))
    {
        resArray[j] = z[i];
        j++
    }
}
```

It'll not be the fastest solution, but it can handle arrays of different lengths.

Edit:

Do not forget to free the memory you've allocated using `new`. 
And you can consider the use of std::vector

Comment: `sizeof` for the size of the initial arrays?

Comment: @JamesKanze my c++ might be a bit rusty, but you're right. This will only get you the number of bytes allocated by the arrays. You still need to divide it by the size of one element.

Comment: In C++, the usual type for an array is `std::vector<T>`; `sizeof` is completely irrelevant.  And even for C style arrays, this code will be in a function, which will have been passed the arrays, so `sizeof` will give you the number of bytes in a pointer.

Comment: Also, of course, there's no reason to believe that this will handle arrays of different lengths correctly.  Of the three obvious ways of handling them (treat it as an error, pad the shorter arrays out with some default value or what you've done), what you've done seems to be the least likely to be what is needed.